# Safari isn't stretching image to flexbox grid

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I'm trying to build a simple teaser grid for featured posts on a website using flexbox. It should look like this:

[image]

And in FF and Chrome it's all good. If i change the resolution of one image, all the others follow and update their size. But not in Safari. Whatever i do, it never fits to an equal height:

[image]

I really don't get the point why this is happening. Each image container on the right has exactly 50% of the height calculated by flexbox. And each image should be stretched to that height.

I could probably achieve this with background-size:cover but i would love to find a solution to use img tags instead.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7tjw8j83/1/

```css
.featured-grid{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit:cover;
}
.left{
  width: 66.6666%;
}
.right{
  width: 33.3333%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.right-top{
   background: green;
   flex: 1;
}
.right-bottom{
   background: red;
   flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-grid">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/450?image=1055">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-top">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400?image=1051">
    </div>
    <div class="right-bottom">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400?image=1057">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7tjw8j83/2/

Comment: Hi @Michael_B, thanks for the fiddle. I see, you are removing the surrounding divs and solving the calculation by flex: 1 0 xx% which is nice, but that i'm not able to put overlay over the images. Any ideas how to put an absolute positioned element over the image?

Comment: I just simplified the code and it works in Safari. But you can still add the image wrappers using the same flex concepts.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think if i start positioning things relative and absolute, everything's getting weird. It's not working if i add overlays to your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/yoeqz92w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Michaels suggestion, you could do like this, where I used `background-image` instead of `img` (since you use a given height anyway), and how to add text at an absolute position

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.featured-grid{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-reapat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
  width: 66.666%;
}
.right{
  width: 33.333%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.right-top{
   flex: 1;
}
.right-bottom{
   flex: 1;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  color: white;     
}
.text > * {
  margin: 5px;     
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-grid">
  <div class="left" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/450?image=1055)">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <h3>Text</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-top" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/400?image=1051)">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bottom" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/400?image=1057)">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.featured-grid{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit:cover;
}
.left {
  width: 66.666%;
}
.right{
  width: 33.333%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.right-top{
   flex: 1;
}
.right-bottom{
   flex: 1;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  color: white;     
}
.text > * {
  margin: 5px;     
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-grid">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/450?image=1055">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <h3>Text</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-top">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400?image=1051">      
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bottom">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400?image=1057">      <div class="text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h3>Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated (2:nd) based on a comment

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.featured-grid {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
}

img.show {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.left img {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.right img {
  max-height: 50vh;
}

.left {
  width: 66.666%;
}

.right {
  width: 33.333%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right-top {
  flex: 1;
}

.right-bottom {
  flex: 1;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.text > * {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-grid">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/250?image=1055">
    <img class="show" src="https://unsplash.it/300/250?image=1055">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <h3>Text 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-top">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/200?image=1057">
      <img class="show" src="https://unsplash.it/300/200?image=1057">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
        <h3>Text 2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bottom">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/200?image=1057">
      <img class="show" src="https://unsplash.it/300/200?image=1057">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Title 3</h2>
        <h3>Text 3</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But as i wrote i would like to solve this with img tags because of the srcset possibilities.

Comment: @KilianSo Added a 2:nd sample using `img` tags

Comment: @KilianSo Do note that `object-fit:cover;` does lack some browser support

Comment: that's where i've been already. It will not work in Safari that way. I made a fiddle with your code and changed the background-images to img-tags - In Chrome and Firefox it's all good but Safari won't stretch the images as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/0hp64pv0/

Comment: @KilianSo And doesn't this work in Safari: https://jsfiddle.net/0hp64pv0/1/

Comment: if you open your updated answer in Safari and view the code snippet in fullscreen, you'll see that this is not working. Still the same behaviour. And yes i now about the object-fit browser support, but Safari doesen't even stretch the images, or squeeze them.

Comment: @KilianSo Did you check my 2 fiddle? ... which Safari version do you use?

Comment: This last fiddle is almost working. https://jsfiddle.net/0hp64pv0/2
But is there a way to not set a height to the .featured-grid container? Like setting the height depending on how tall the images are.

Comment: That's neat! But in every Browser i tested, it's still stretching to the full height of the window. I thought of using the actual image height to define the container height. Now it's just stretching to the available space.

Comment: @KilianSo Added a 3:rd sample ... using smaller images so you can see it actually does not stretch to full window height, also added `max-height` to make it responsive